# Python Import data dictionary and pattern

Tags: python, dictionary, pattern-matching

If I have data as:

```
Code, data_1, data_2, data_3, [....], data204700

a,1,1,0, ... , 1
b,1,0,0, ... , 1
a,1,1,0, ... , 1
c,0,1,0, ... , 1
b,1,0,0, ... , 1
etc. same code different value (0, 1, ?(not known))
```

I need to create a big matrix and I want to analyze.

1. **How can I import data in a dictionary?**

I want to use dictionary for column (204.700+1)

1. **There is a built in function (or package) that return to me pattern?**

   (I expect a percent pattern). I mean as 90% of 1 in column 1, 80% of in column 2.

Comment: A dictionary is a collection of key-value pairs. What do you want for your keys, and what do you want for the values?

Comment: if there is an integer, must it be a 0 or 1? or could there be a 2 or another number? and is it basically all columns that are not the first will consist of 0s or 1s?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Alright so I am going to assume you want this in a dictionary for storing purposes and I will tell you that you don't want that with this kind of data. use a [pandas](http://pandas.pydata.org/) `DataFrame`

this is how you will get your code into a dataframe:

```
import pandas as pd
my_file = 'file_name'
df = pd.read_csv(my_file)
```

now you don't need a package for returning the pattern you are looking for, just write a simple algorithm for returning that!

```
def one_percentage(data):
    #get total number of rows for calculating percentages
    size = len(data)
    #get type so only grabbing the correct rows
    x = data.columns[1]
    x = data[x].dtype
    #list of touples to hold amount of 1s and the column names
    ones = [(i,sum(data[i])) for i in data if data[i].dtype == x]
    my_dict = {}
    #create dictionary with column names and percent
    for x in ones:
        percent = x[1]/float(size)
        my_dict[x[0]] = percent
    return my_dict
```

now if you want to get the percent of ones in any column, this is what you do:

```
percentages = one_percentage(df)
column_name = 'any_column_name'
print percentages[column_name]
```

now if you want to have it do every single column, then you can grab all of the column names and loop through them:

```
columns = [name for name in percentages]
for name in columns:
    print str(percentages[name]) + "% of 1 in column " + name
```

let me know if you need anything else!

Comment: Thanks. I have in mind the same kind of solution. We have to add a third value (that is ?- unknown). I will also try with Orange package!